# Import sql to pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to import sql in my pgAdmin

```
ERROR:  role "dream_house" does not exist
SQL state: 42704
```

But I can not import, What I should do ???

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that it is expecting a user-name or role named "dream_house".

"Import sql in pgAdmin" is not clearly stating what you are intending to achieve. If you give a clear explanation of what you are trying to do, someone here may be able to help you.